# Error al traducir página con Angular-Translate

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de implemantar `angular-translate` en mi página. Pero en el momento de solicitar el cambio de idioma me marca el siguiente error:

> $translate.uses is not a function

app.js

```
var ole_no_ldap_validate=angular.module("ole_no_ldap_validate",['ngRoute','localization','pascalprecht.translate']);

    ole_no_ldap_validate.config(function ($translateProvider){
        $translateProvider.translations('es',{
            '_save_': 'Lista de Tareas',
            '_employeeName_': 'Nombre del Empleado',
            '_employeeNumber_': 'Numero de empleado',
            '_organization_': 'organizacion',
            '_country_': 'pais'
        });

        $translateProvider.translations('en',{
            '_save_': 'List',
            '_employeeName_': 'Employee name',
            '_employeeNumber_': 'Employee number',
            '_organization_': 'Organization',
            '_country_': 'Country'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    });
```

Controller.js

```
ole_no_ldap_validate.controller("ole_no_ldap_validateController",['$scope', '$http','$translate',function($scope, $http, $translate) {

    $scope.context = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));

    $scope.ChabgeLanguaje=function(idioma){
        $translate.uses(idioma);
    };
```

page.jsp

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" tabindex="5" ng-click="ChabgeLanguaje('es');">
                    <span class="ion-search"></span>
                    <span>ES</span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" tabindex="5" ng-click="ChabgeLanguaje('en');">
                    <span class="ion-search"></span>
                    <span>EN</span>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate), el método para cambar el lenguaje en `$tranlate` es `use`, (te sobra la `s`)

```
$translate.use("en_US").then(function(data){ $scope.text = $translate("HELLO"); });
```

Comment: He pasado mucho en la computadora, era eso. Muchas gracias

Comment: @EdgarConrado De nada. Cámbiate a TypeScript y eso no te pasará porque tienes tipado y auto-completado ;-)